# Unit testing database: no such table: migrations

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

Trying to use an in-memory `testing` database for my unit tests. It seems that it can't even run the migrations, because the `migrations` table does not exist.

Here is my code:

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // use testing database
        $this->setUpDatabase();
    }

    public function setUpDatabase()
    {
        $this->app['config']->set('database', [
            'default' => 'testing',
            'connections' => [
                'testing' => [
                    'driver' => 'sqlite',
                    'database' => ':memory:',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

This gives me the error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: migrations

Not only that, but it also seems to be running migrations on my main database.

Comment: Try moving the `parent::setUp()` after the `$this->setUpDatabase` but keep in mind `$this->app` might not be set yet so you might need to manipulate the underlying environment config. Alternatively set up environment variables in `phpunit.xml`

Comment: Why are you setting these config options in your test?  Put them in `.env.testing` or `phpunit.xml`

Comment: Because this is for a package. I can not modify the .env file.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  Why would you need to hard code the testing DB for a package?

Comment: Because the package should use its own testing database. I don't want to have to force people to setup their own testing database just to run unit tests for my package.

Comment: The unit tests in your package are for you to run.  Package test are rarely included in the test suite for the consumers of the package.  Either way, testing data is not persistent so it doesn't even matter if they were to run your unit tests on the same databases,  that's the whole purpose of refreshing the database between tests.

Comment: OK, thank you for your advice.